# Why can't I access data from another file even though I have it exported and required where needed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to clear the cookie from the routes directory, but have the cookie name declared in the main js file. I have the paths.js file required in the main js file, but every time I try to clear the cookie it says, ReferenceError: SESS_NAME is not defined

## Main js file

```
       app.use(session({
         name: SESS_NAME,
         resave: false,
         saveUninitialized: false,
         secret: SESS_SECRET,
       }),
       cookie: {
         maxAge: SESS_LIFETIME,
         sameSite: true,
         secure: IN_PROD
         }
       })); 

        app.use("/", require("./routes/paths"));
```

## Paths js file

```
    router.route("/blog").get((req, res) => {
      req.session.destroy((err) => {
        if (err) 
           console.log(err);
        else
           res.clearCookie(SESS_NAME);
      });

         });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SESS_NAME, SESS_LIFETIME and IN_PROD are constants declared somewhere. Make sure they are imported in the Main.js file or declare them in Main.js file

As these are constants,  I suggest move them to a constants.js file and import as and when needed in both Main.js and Paths.js

constants.js

```
module.exports = Object.freeze({
    MY_CONSTANT: 'some value',
    ANOTHER_CONSTANT: 'another value'
});
```

in Main.js and Path.js

```
var constants = require("./constants");
console.log(constants.MY_CONSTANT);
```

Comment: I do have them declared in the main.js file, right above the app.use(session()), I have given them initial values. I am getting the error from the paths.js file, but I already have this file required in main.js, so that's my question. If I have paths.js required in main.js, why am I receiving this error?

Comment: You should declare SESS_NAME in paths.js too.

Comment: This seems like a good idea, but would that not negate if from being used in the app.use(session()) ?

Comment: You can import it anywhere you want to use. The reason for moving to a separate file is, you need to edit only the constants file and the changes will reflect everywhere it used as import, rather than having multiple constants declared everywhere throughout the app

Answer (score 0):

> If I have paths.js required in main.js, why am I receiving this error? (from your comment)

This is because before your module gets executed it gets wrapped inside a function by node.

so your code basically gets translated to this

```
(function(exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) {
  // your main.js

 });
```

so now its clear that your all the variable defined inside this can only be accessed by your main.js file.

Solution 1-
Put all your constants in a separate file and import them wherever your need.

Solution 2-

```
// paths.js

const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router();
module.exports = (SESS_NAME)=>{
  router.route("/blog").get((req, res) => {
    req.session.destroy((err) => {
      if (err) 
       console.log(err);
      else
       res.clearCookie(SESS_NAME);
  });

     });

  return router;
}

// main.js

  app.use("/", require("./routes/paths")(SESS_NAME));
```